# Could not convert string to float in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to make a ML model , but I am having problems with this one feature. The error given is saying , cannot convert string to float. I tried using a convert method but it is still not working. This code tries to make a ml model

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

crime_data = pd.read_csv('Crime_Data_from_2020_to_Present.csv')
#offense = crime_data['Crm Cd Desc']
myData = crime_data.drop(columns=['DR_NO', 'Date Rptd', 'Rpt Dist No', 'Part 1-2', 'Crm Cd', 'Mocodes', 'Vict Age', 'Vict Sex', 'Vict Descent', 'Premis Desc', 'Weapon Used Cd', 'Weapon Desc', 'Status', 'Status Desc', 'Crm Cd 1', 'Crm Cd 2', 'Crm Cd 3', 'Crm Cd 4', 'Cross Street', 'Premis Cd'])
myData['DATE OCC'] = myData['DATE OCC'].astype(float) # Method for converting not working

X = myData.drop (columns=['AREA NAME']) # Input data
y = myData['AREA NAME'] # Output data

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 50)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-20d49933ca7e> in <module>
  9 #offense= crime_data['Crm Cd Desc']
 10 myData= crime_data.drop(columns=['DR_NO','Date Rptd','Rpt Dist No','Part 1-2','Crm Cd','Mocodes','Vict Age','Vict Sex','Vict Descent','Premis Desc','Weapon Used Cd','Weapon Desc','Status','Status Desc','Crm Cd 1','Crm Cd 2','Crm Cd 3','Crm Cd 4','Cross Street','Premis Cd'])
 ---> 11 myData['DATE OCC'] = myData['DATE OCC'].astype(float)#method for converting not working
 12
 13 X= myData.drop (columns=['AREA NAME']) #input data

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
 5696         else:
 5697             # else, only a single dtype is given
 -> 5698             new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
 5699             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
 5700

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
580
581     def astype(self, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise"):
--> 582         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
583
584     def convert(self, **kwargs):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, filter, **kwargs)
440                 applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
441             else:
--> 442                 applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
443             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
444

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
623             vals1d = values.ravel()
624             try:
--> 625                 values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
626             except (ValueError, TypeError):
627                 # e.g. astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
895     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
896         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
--> 897         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
898
899     return arr.view(dtype)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '01/08/2020 12:00:00 AM'
```

I changed the code to this:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

crime_data = pd.read_csv('Crime_Data_from_2020_to_Present.csv')
#offense = crime_data['Crm Cd Desc']
myData = crime_data.drop(columns=['DR_NO', 'Date Rptd', 'Rpt Dist No', 'Part 1-2', 'Crm Cd', 'Mocodes', 'Vict Age', 'Vict Sex', 'Vict Descent', 'Premis Desc', 'Weapon Used Cd', 'Weapon Desc', 'Status', 'Status Desc', 'Crm Cd 1', 'Crm Cd 2', 'Crm Cd 3', 'Crm Cd 4', 'Cross Street', 'Premis Cd'])
myData['DATE OCC'] = pd.to_datetime(myData['DATE OCC']) # Method for converting not working

X = myData.drop (columns=['AREA NAME']) # Input data
y = myData['AREA NAME'] # Output data

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 50)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred
```

But then I get this error. How can I fix it?

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-17-18d34976fcb7> in <module>
 16 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
 17 classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 50)
 ---> 18 classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
 19 y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
 20 y_pred

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
301                 "sparse multilabel-indicator for y is not supported."
302             )
--> 303         X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, multi_output=True,
304                                    accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
305         if sample_weight is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
430                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
431             else:
--> 432                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
433             out = X, y
434

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
 71                           FutureWarning)
 72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
 ---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
 74     return inner_f
 75

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
794         raise ValueError("y cannot be None")
795
--> 796     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
797                     accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
798                     dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
 71                           FutureWarning)
 72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
 ---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
 74     return inner_f
 75

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)enter code here
532
533         if all(isinstance(dtype, np.dtype) for dtype in dtypes_orig):
--> 534             dtype_orig = np.result_type(*dtypes_orig)
535
536     if dtype_numeric:

<__array_function__ internals> in result_type(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

Comment: This is a `scikit-learn` question, and it has nothing specifically to do with `jupyter-notebook` or `anaconda`; please mind your tags, they are here for a reason (edited).

Comment: Please post a sample so we can see what your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

There is a column named `DATE OCC` in your dataset which has date and time mentioned in it. You are getting that error because, your model is expecting float values and that `DATE OCC` column you have is in `object` or `datetime64` format. So you have to add this code that I mentioned below:

```
myData['DATE OCC'] = myData['DATE OCC'].astype('datetime64')

myData['day'] = myData['DATE OCC'].dt.day
myData['month'] = myData['DATE OCC'].dt.month
myData['Year'] = myData['DATE OCC'].dt.year

del myData['DATE OCC']

myData = pd.get_dummies(myData)

X= myData.drop(columns=['AREA NAME']) #input data
y= myData['AREA NAME'] #output data
```